# .htaccess URL ReWrite Wordpress Old Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have a blog which had old date based permalinks. EG: Blog.com/2011/10/post-name

My new permalinks now are category and post name based, but also are preceded by /blog/. EG: Blog.com/blog/category-name/post-name

What do i need to do in my HT Access file to overcome thins? I have something like this so far but currently not working..

```
#RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/.*$ /blog/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Your original URLs did not have a category, so just using the input URL (in .htaccess) its not possible to redirect to a URL that has a category, unless all the items are in the same category, or you have rule that can be used to derive the category from the post name

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that Wordpress picks up this redirect automatically. So if you just go to the new permalink /blog/2011/10/post-name it redirects you too /blog/category/post-name

Answer (score 0):

If `/blog/2011/10/post-name` already redirects you too `/blog/category/post-name` (make sure it is a 301), then all you need to do is to send 
`/2011/10/post-name` to `/blog/2011/10/post-name`

You can do this by putting the rules below in the .htaccess file in the root of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#redirect blogs posts to /blog
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/.+)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it has to do with moving the site from /blog/ to root; is that the case?

If so, you should find/replace the URLs in the database as to not have to use a .htaccess rule.

This query run in phpmyadmin will update post guid's to get rid of the /blog/ path:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.domain.com/blog/','http://www.domain.com/');
```

You may also need to change URLs in post content:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.domain.com/blog/', 'http://www.domain.com/');
```